# Event observer not firing from custom module when coupon is applied on checkout page

Tags: php, xml, events, magento, observer-pattern

I want to do something after a coupon is applied during the checkout process.  I used the 'catalogrule_after_apply' event along with the corresponding function in Observer.php. The coupon is still being applied without hitting my observer method. I have other events firing, so invalid xml wouldn't be the case.  The issue might be the event i am using, but i cant find any other event that would yield the same effect.  Suggestions?

etc/config.xml

```
<config>
       <events>
            <catalogrule_after_apply>
                <observers>
                    <promosource>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>promosource/observer</class>
                        <method>addSourceIdToSessionFromCoupon</method>
                    </promosource>
                </observers>
            </catalogrule_after_apply>
        </events>
</config>
```

Helper/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Russ_Promosource_Model_Observer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function addSourceIdToSessionFromCoupon($observer) {

                die ('event observer worked');
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the event you're observing is triggered when you click on the "Apply Rule", in the admin.
For what you wanna do, I'd use the `salesrule_validator_process` event. You're observer could then access the applied rule:

```
    public function couponApplied($observer)
    {
        $rule = $observer->getEvent()->getRule();
        $couponCode = $rule->getCouponCode();
        $ruleId = $rule->getRuleId();
    }
```

HTH